# How to use DocuSign on behalf of a single user, but with dynamic redirection post signing ceremony?

Tags: docusignapi

My use case is thus:

1. I will have access to a single DocuSign account which would belong to Acme Inc. (I am currently using a sandbox account).
2. Acme Inc. has many branches, each with it's own employees with different documents that they must sign depending on which branch they work in.
3. From my internal application, the Admins of the branches will upload documents and set the emails addresses that the documents must be sent to.
4. The employees will complete the signing ceremony after following the link in the mail that they will receive.
5. **MAIN ISSUE** - Once the signing ceremony is complete, I require the employee to be redirected to a certain page of the internal application where they must complete some additional steps.

What I have so far:

I ran the example provided [here](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-node-auth-code-grant). The issue with this is the permission request. I do not want an access prompt, rather, I want this done in the Admin Panel itself so that requests to the DocuSign API from my Server Application contain a valid token or receive a new one in case the existing one has expired. I saw from [here](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication) that the JWT Grant system fit my use case, and I ran that using consent from a single user, however, I am stuck trying to figure out how to redirect the signer (employee) to the page I want with some parameters in the redirection URI. This can be as simple as the one provided (`state=123`) in the (`eg-01`) Embedded Signing example provided with the Auth Grant sample.

I apologize for not having any code snippet to show as I have not integrated anything into my internal application as of yet, I am merely running the code from the GitHub examples. Please let me know if I need to provide any additional information in order to facilitate your understanding of my requirements.

Any help provided would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your main issue is the authentication type you are using.
You used the example showing Auth Code Grant, which does require users to log in.
You could instead use JWT (JSON Web Token) which does not require that (only once, and that can be done by you).
The code for making APIs and redirecting after signing ceremony etc. is the same. All you have to do is change the code that was used to obtain the access token (and also you need some configuration changes).
You can find nodeJS example of JWT here - https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-node-jwt

If you want to read more about JWT - https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-jsonwebtoken

Comment: Thanks Inbvar, I was able to use the code from the Auth Code Grant example using JWTs instead, my problem has been solved.